# how to write select query for work break time

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to calculate days between two dates. (work break time)
How can I write select query for this requirement, is it possible?

`JOB_START_DATE (minus) PREVIOUS(JOB_END_DATE)`

```
USERID  JOB_START_DATE      JOB_END_DATE
212390  07/25/2017          10/31/2017 
212390  11/27/2017          12/19/2017 
212390  10/16/2018          02/04/2019
```

For Example;

```
11/27/2017 - 10/31/2017 
10/16/2018 - 12/19/2017
```

Expected Result:

```
   Days
    27
    301
```

[image]

Comment: Specify the expected result as well.

Comment: `lag` to get previous end, just substract provided  columns are `DATE` type

Comment: Thank you @Serg. Do you have sample LAG query?

Comment: LAG(JOB_END_DATE, 1) OVER (ORDER BY JOB_START_DATE) AS prev_end_end_date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Lag](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions070.htm) example :

```
SELECT USERID, JOB_START_DATE, JOB_END_DATE
   , lag(JOB_END_DATE) over(partition by USERID order by JOB_START_DATE) - JOB_START_DATE as break
FROM ...
```